# How am I supposed to use diff in this situation?

Tags: git, diff

I recently asked a Google Groups forum for help with setting up a Vagrant/Chef/Django VM thingamajigger, and I received the following help:

> The fabfile.py had some errors for me. After I fixed them everything
>   seemed to work.
>   **Apply the diff** and tell me if a 'fab vagrant:honza bootstrap’ works properly.
>
> ```
> ==========
> diff --git a/fabfile.py b/fabfile.py
> index 90716b1..918f6f3 100644
> --- a/fabfile.py
> +++ b/fabfile.py
> @@ -76,7 +76,7 @@ def set_env_for_user(user='example'):
>          data = parse_ssh_config(result)
>
>          try:
> -            env.host_string = 'vagrant@127.0.0.1:%s' % data['Port']
> +            env.host_string = 'vagrant@%s:%s' % (data['HostName'], data['Port'])
>              env.key_filename = data['IdentityFile'].strip('"')
>          except KeyError:
>              raise Exception("Missing data from ssh-config")
> @@ -191,11 +191,11 @@ def vagrant(username):
>
>      env.remote = 'vagrant'
>      env.branch = 'master'
> -    env.host = '127.0.0.1'
> +    env.host = data['HostName']
>      env.port = data['Port']
>
>      try:
> -        env.host_string = '%s@127.0.0.1:%s' % (username, data['Port'])
> +        env.host_string = '%s@%s:%s' % (username, data['HostName'], data['Port'])
>      except KeyError:
>          raise Exception("Missing data from ssh-config")
> ==========
> ```

As far as I know, `diff` is only used to compare two files, and `diff --git` is not a real command. What exactly am I being told to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have in front of you is a so-called "patch file". A patch file contains instructions to change a given file from one version to another. In this example, you already have the file and it is assumed to be version *A*. The patch file changes it to a version *B*.

You need to apply this patch with the `patch` command:

```
patch -p1 < path/to/patchfile.patch
```

You might need to change the number for the `-p` option to strip leading path components from the filenames given in the patch.

See also: [Applying patches | Drupal.org](https://drupal.org/patch/apply)

Comment: Thanks. Well, this raises some more questions for me then: Why `index 90716b1..918f6f3 100644`, and `--- a/fabfile.py
+++ b/fabfile.py
@@ -76,7 +76,7 @@ def set_env_for_user(user='example'):
         data = parse_ssh_config(result)`? If i had two files, one of which was correct, and the other one not so correct, I think I could use your command, but what he gave me is not a patched version of the file. I'm still very confused.

Comment: This patch file is generated from a [Git repository](http://git-scm.com/) and shows you the difference of the file between two revisions (`90716b1` and `918f6f3` are Git commit identifiers). The `a` and `b` just refer to the hypothetical paths of the files in both revisions. In your case, you already have the file `fabfile.py`, assumed to be version `a`, and by applying the patch you'd end up with version `b`. It doesn't matter if your current file is actually from a Git repository or not. The patch file just contains instructions to change it from A to B.

Comment: Alright, I got what you told me to do to work. We'll find out later if the guy's fix was solid or not because `vagrant up` takes a while. For now, thanks a lot man. That was a really good answer and follow-up. Tell me if I did it right, though, if you will. I made a file called mypatchfile.patch with vi in the same directory as fabfile.py ,and then I used sublime to copy and paste everything in between his double bars into the file. Then I ran `patch -p1 < mypatchfile.patch` from within the same dir. It returned `patching file fabfile.py`, so I think it worked!

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what should happen! Good luck solving your further issues.